# Matthew 1:18; what is the meaning of "found with child of the Holy Ghost"?

Tags: matthew, pneumatology

Matthew 1:18; DRB;

> 18 Now the generation of Christ was in this wise. When as his mother Mary was espoused to Joseph, before they came together, she was found with child, of the Holy Ghost.

Was Mary pregnant with a child of the Holy Ghost?

What is the meaning of being pregnant with a child of **metaphysical** entity like the Holy Ghost?

Answer (score 1):

The last (and pertinent) phrase of Matt 1:18 is:

> εὑρέθη ἐν γαστρὶ ἔχουσα ἐκ πνεύματος ἁγίου. = she was found in womb
> having [a child] out of the Holy Spirit

Luke provides only slightly more detail in Luke 1:34, 35:

> “How can this be,” Mary asked the angel, “since I am a virgin?”
>
> The angel replied, “The Holy Spirit will come upon you, and the power
> of the Most High will overshadow you. So the Holy One to be born will
> be called the Son of God.

Thus, the Bible is very clear - to use modern medical jargon, Mary was inseminated by a miracle of the Holy Spirit.

Answer (score 1):

The spirit of God^ enabled the pregnancy. A normal pregnancy as any mother would have , Jesus was born of the flesh - in which he died.

> Put to death in the flesh, he was brought to life in the spirit 1Pet 3:18

Even after his resurrection, he said he wasn't a spirit. God says flesh begets flesh, and spirit begets spirit.

> That which is born of the flesh is flesh, and that which is born of the Spirit is spirit. John 3:6

Jesus being born of Mary is that fleshly result - he is not spirit before he died and not after he died. So he is not a *product* of the Holy Spirit - being spirit. He is a product of Mary, being flesh, *enabled* by the **power** of God.

> the angel answering, said to her, "The Holy Spirit will come upon you, and **the power of the Most High** will overshadow you; therefore also the Holy One being born will be called the Son of God. Luke 1:35

Echoed here with,

> Now the **generation of Christ** was in this wise Matt 1:18

**Was Mary pregnant with a child of the Holy Spirit?**

No, she was made *able* to be pregnant by God - via the power of His spirit. As noted often, God is Jesus' Father - Jesus being the 'son of God' in many verses, he is not the son of the Holy Spirit as if it was somehow acting independently of God or the Father to make Mary conceive. Similarly, we see this expression of power in many places.

> Now may the God of hope fill you with all joy and peace in believing, so that you will abound in hope **by the power of** the Holy Spirit. Rom 15:13

> Jesus returned to Galilee in the power of the spirit Luke 4:14

> you will receive power when the holy spirit comes upon you Acts 1:8

^The spirit of God is the same as the Holy Spirit which is the same as the spirit of the Father - explained [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/53177/is-holy-spirit-the-spirit-of-the-father-according-to-luke-and-matthew/55619?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C73.9169#55619).

Comment: Which is also the same as the spirit of Christ.  "...**therefore** also the Holy One being born will be called the Son of God."  If all the Holy Spirit did was enable Mary to have a human child without a male gamete then he would not have been called the Son of God.  Therefore is there for a reason:)